# How to add new picklist values in Feed Item Type, so that they can be available in Feed Filter Criteria during feed filter creation

Tags: feeditem, casefeed

I wanted to create a Feed Filter which can display only Tracked changes.But Tracked Change is not available in Feed Filter criteria. Is there any way to add that value under Feed Item Type. [image]

Answer (score 0):

just go to the object field definition page 
and in the fields and relationship
just edit the Feed Item type Picklist
and you can add you new vaalue in the picklist and save it again

I hope above solution will be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately Feed related objects were not available from set up.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Case page layout : You will find feed View click on that after that you will find all options

[image]

for more details you can visit this link:

**Use Feed Filters to Manage Your Feed**
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/service_casefeed_basics/service_casefeed_basics_filters

I hope above information will be helpful.

Comment: My concern is not about adding a new feed filter to the case page layout Feed View. While creating the new Feed filter, there is an option to select the feed item type and "Tracked Change" is not available under the available options. Is it possible to include a new option such as "Tracked Change"  under Feed  Item type in Feed filter criterai?

Comment: Can you tell me Tracked Change value is related to which object? i mean in which object 'Tracked changed' is present?

Comment: Hello Rohit, All the feed related objects were not available from set up. I have raised a case with salesforce.com and got the reply as as of not it is not possible to include new values under feed Item Type. Anyhow thanks for the quick response.